# PKI not choosable on Android-Phone

Tags: android, client-certificates, pki, mutual-authentication

I try to login using PKI. I use this tutorial: http://release-manager.com/rest/images/12702

On firefox this works well. On Android-Smartphone this does not work (I tried several phones Android 6-11).**EDIT: Fortunately Android 7.1.1 seems to works.**

[image]

This is the p12-File:

https://node1.sandbox.release-manager.com/rest/cloud/download/433/?pw=2cf6576250ed0e348a20c2580ee7e092&un=sandbox

It must have something todo with the p12 key.

This is a screenshot of the kse:

[image]

This is the ASN1 Structure

```
SEQUENCE
{
    SEQUENCE
    {
        TAGGED [0]:
            INTEGER=2
        INTEGER=512434666 (0x1e8b21ea)
        SEQUENCE
        {
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER=Sha256WithRSAEncryption (1.2.840.113549.1.1.11)
            NULL
        }
        SEQUENCE
        {
            SET
            {
                SEQUENCE
                {
                    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=CountryName (2.5.4.6)
                    PRINTABLE STRING='US'
                }
            }
            SET
            {
                SEQUENCE
                {
                    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=OrganizationName (2.5.4.10)
                    UTF8 STRING='[]'
                }
            }
            SET
            {
                SEQUENCE
                {
                    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=OrganizationalUnitName (2.5.4.11)
                    UTF8 STRING='[]'
                }
            }
            SET
            {
                SEQUENCE
                {
                    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=CommonName (2.5.4.3)
                    PRINTABLE STRING='www.e-nexus.de'
                }
            }
        }
        SEQUENCE
        {
            UTC TIME=10/Nov/2000 00:00:00 CET (001109230000GMT+00:00)
            GENERALIZED TIME=10/Nov/2100 00:00:00.000 CET (21001109230000GMT+00:00)
        }
        SEQUENCE
        {
            SET
            {
                SEQUENCE
                {
                    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=CountryName (2.5.4.6)
                    PRINTABLE STRING='US'
                }
            }
            SET
            {
                SEQUENCE
                {
                    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=OrganizationName (2.5.4.10)
                    UTF8 STRING='[]'
                }
            }
            SET
            {
                SEQUENCE
                {
                    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=OrganizationalUnitName (2.5.4.11)
                    UTF8 STRING='[]'
                }
            }
            SET
            {
                SEQUENCE
                {
                    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=CommonName (2.5.4.3)
                    PRINTABLE STRING='Admin Example Node 1'
                }
            }
        }
        SEQUENCE
        {
            SEQUENCE
            {
                OBJECT IDENTIFIER=RsaEncryption (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1)
                NULL
            }
            BIT STRING, encapsulates:
                SEQUENCE
                {
                    INTEGER=
                        00 96 2D D5 EB 60 BB 98   ..-Õë`».
                        71 B6 A5 62 85 08 5D FD   q¶¥b..]ý
                        42 80 CF 89 D4 B0 1D 46   B.Ï.Ô°.F
                        38 36 B1 DF 29 6F 52 34   86±ß)oR4
                        28 D1 A7 8A 67 21 C1 C6   (Ñ§.g!ÁÆ
                        31 77 3B D3 B5 EE A8 9E   1w;Óµî¨.
                        01 D4 A2 36 FC 12 88 15   .Ô¢6ü...
                        43 69 70 38 FC 81 B6 3D   Cip8ü.¶=
                        DF E4 6D 09 77 F3 9B 27   ßäm.wó.'
                        AC 01 A3 4A 41 77 55 21   ¬.£JAwU!
                        B9 68 61 AA AD 50 34 F0   ¹haª­P4ð
                        AC 62 76 3C 2E 50 6E 44   ¬bv<.PnD
                        55 88 C0 0E 02 0E 36 6E   U.À...6n
                        A4 AA 5D E3 FC 7A 64 6A   ¤ª]ãüzdj
                        ED 0A CA 1B B3 CE 31 2D   í.Ê.³Î1-
                        2F 10 96 89 F1 5A 02 62   /...ñZ.b
                        8B A1 F6 1A 5F BA AE 6B   .¡ö._º®k
                        84 CC 97 40 3B 3D F3 3C   .Ì.@;=ó<
                        E2 AB 15 D5 16 BE 22 35   â«.Õ.¾"5
                        10 A4 5A 6D 0E 4D 6A 34   .¤Zm.Mj4
                        12 BA 01 DD 6D A5 7D B5   .º.Ým¥}µ
                        4E 61 59 16 92 1A 5B E9   NaY...[é
                        22 8D A1 CC 51 1A DA BE   ".¡ÌQ.Ú¾
                        DC EB 6F C9 49 16 72 3F   ÜëoÉI.r?
                        50 52 0A 65 95 BE 13 7B   PR.e.¾.{
                        18 F1 D5 31 23 28 19 14   .ñÕ1#(..
                        BE 2D D3 E3 BF 90 9A 4F   ¾-Óã¿..O
                        49 DE 92 D1 7C 3E 72 BE   IÞ.Ñ|>r¾
                        72 52 15 F3 30 5A 69 2C   rR.ó0Zi,
                        5B DD 1F 01 4D C1 2C 8F   [Ý..MÁ,.
                        A1 A3 62 8A DF 73 52 39   ¡£b.ßsR9
                        4D 61 EA 2E 10 37 5D 87   Maê..7].
                        53                        S
                    INTEGER=65537 (0x10001)
                }

        }
        TAGGED [3]:
            SEQUENCE
            {
                SEQUENCE
                {
                    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=ExtKeyUsage (2.5.29.37)
                    BOOLEAN=true
                    OCTET STRING, encapsulates:
                        SEQUENCE
                        {
                            OBJECT IDENTIFIER=ClientAuth (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
                        }

                }
                SEQUENCE
                {
                    OBJECT IDENTIFIER=SubjectKeyIdentifier (2.5.29.14)
                    OCTET STRING, encapsulates:
                        OCTET STRING=
                            11 25 D9 96 7E E1 16 B5   .%Ù.~á.µ
                            28 5D D7 65 81 22 0D BF   (]×e.".¿
                            6C E8 27 71               lè'q

                }
            }
    }
    SEQUENCE
    {
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER=Sha256WithRSAEncryption (1.2.840.113549.1.1.11)
        NULL
    }
    BIT STRING=
        4C 02 52 BF 5D 8D 82 F0   L.R¿]..ð
        89 DB 14 4E 46 95 C6 8B   .Û.NF.Æ.
        01 3A AF 7B 29 C0 25 FA   .:¯{)À%ú
        85 7A 93 29 90 93 AA 2E   .z.)..ª.
        06 B6 28 F7 3B 9B 58 38   .¶(÷;.X8
        7C 67 D1 E7 B2 AE 3C 75   |gÑç²®<u
        74 A8 26 CC 6E 6D 79 F4   t¨&Ìnmyô
        2B 73 CA 2D A1 9C 12 0E   +sÊ-¡...
        51 CF 6D 2E D2 86 14 E1   QÏm.Ò..á
        34 96 DB E4 03 51 E6 70   4.Ûä.Qæp
        04 2D 9F 1C C3 06 78 98   .-..Ã.x.
        7D AA 96 4D B0 6D BA A1   }ª.M°mº¡
        4A 92 AD 3A FA 9A D4 98   J.­:ú.Ô.
        9A 57 2A CF 9D 58 C4 20   .W*Ï.XÄ 
        BE C6 E7 F6 63 B4 A0 E2   ¾Æçöc´ â
        8D B6 1C 96 BA 0A C8 D2   .¶..º.ÈÒ
        C6 E2 BC 9C 38 1F 44 31   Æâ¼.8.D1
        1F 72 47 D0 FE EA 89 00   .rGÐþê..
        45 2F C7 4E 2B 14 88 3D   E/ÇN+..=
        64 0D 8F 57 81 C5 6F DD   d..W.ÅoÝ
        90 24 0E 9B 18 6D D4 E2   .$...mÔâ
        BE 30 B9 A8 E7 E8 0F E6   ¾0¹¨çè.æ
        1A B8 22 57 92 5A 08 0F   .¸"W.Z..
        D7 56 85 E7 89 3E 46 C6   ×V.ç.>FÆ
        0E 60 C3 CB 12 1D EE D3   .`ÃË..îÓ
        90 88 BF 8E 79 AF 04 51   ..¿.y¯.Q
        67 49 FA 6B 14 32 D8 2D   gIúk.2Ø-
        CB 88 80 A7 40 36 04 4D   Ë..§@6.M
        77 90 2A 54 50 C9 EB 83   w.*TPÉë.
        DA 19 56 B4 C8 09 97 C0   Ú.V´È..À
        A3 0E 7D 1D AC 6B 86 CF   £.}.¬k.Ï
        5E 80 60 10 5F 32 F0 68   ^.`._2ðh
}
```

Comment: So you've tried: [How do you use a .p12 certificate on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65888246/295004) What is the output of the [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat)? Maybe useful [Install self-signed certificates no longer working in Android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58500892/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang The problem  is about the selection of the certificate, not the installation. The certificate is installed well, no problem here. Logcat show no error.

Comment: Tried the certificate with Chrome 91.0.4472.164 and Android 7.1.1 on https://release-manager.com : I selected the certificate, then got a page saying "release-manager.com didn't accept your login certificate"

Comment: @bwt instead of release-manager.com try node1.sandbox.release-manager.com . You gave me an interresting point: Chrome 91.0.4472.164 and Android 7.1.1 let you select the certificate!!! Very interresting! I use Android 11.

Comment: on node1.sandbox.release-manager.com it works (I land on a page with a logout button)

Comment: @bwt Can you please tell me what Cellphone-Model you are using?

Comment: it was a Honeywell CT60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is related to [this Android 10 behaviour change](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#keychain) : certificates are now filtered according to the criteria sent by the server.

In your case the server requires a certificate issued by `Admin Example Node 1` (or at least pretends to) :

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect node1.sandbox.release-manager.com:443 -servername node1.sandbox.release-manager.com

...
Acceptable client certificate CA names
C = US, O = [], OU = [], CN = Admin Example Node 1
...
```

(Please note that the `O` and `OU` are not empty, they contain the string `[]` and the CA fields must match)

But your certificate is issued by `www.e-nexus.de` :

```
keytool -v -list -storetype PKCS12 -keystore Admin_Example_Node_1_210420063319.p12

...
Alias name: admin example node 1
Creation date: Apr 19, 2021
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Admin Example Node 1, OU=[], O=[], C=US
Issuer: CN=www.e-nexus.de, OU=[], O=[], C=US
```

I created a CA named CN =`Admin Example Node 1`, C = `US`, O = `[]`, OU = `[]` and used it to issue a certificate :

```
Alias name: 1
Creation date: Jul 25, 2021
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 2
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=hello2, OU=[], O=[], C=US
Issuer: CN=Admin Example Node 1, OU=[], O=[], C=US
```

Edit : I tested 3 certificates :

- yours
- a certificate issued by a CA named `CN=Admin Example Node 1, OU=[], O=[], C=US`
- a certificate issued by a CA named `CN=Admin Example Node 1, C=US`

On :

- Android 7.1 (Honeywell CT60)
- Android 8.0 (Samsung A3 2017)
- Andoid 9 (Datalogic)
- Android 10 (Honeywell CT40)
- Android 12 beta3 (Pixel 3a)

With the results :

- On devices pre Android 10, Chrome offered the 3 certificates
- On Android 10+ the popup showed only the certificate matching the server specifications (issued by `CN=Admin Example Node 1, OU=[], O=[], C=US`)

So the solution would be to change either the CA name or  the specification sent by the server.